# Determining if a function is Onto and Many One

Tags: functions

If $f(x)= x^3 + 3x^2 + 12x - 2\sin x$ where $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, then prove that $f(x)$ is one-one and onto.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know the definitions of one-one or onto, or at least a geometric idea?

Comment: look at [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3+%2B+3x%5E2+%2B+12x+-+2+sinx] and draw conclusions

Comment: Yes i have differentiating the given function but then i cant undertsand what to conclude if the derivative contains a polynomial and sine function.

Comment: The main problem is that i am getting confused because there are algebraic and trigonometric functions  together.

Comment: and Mr. Bongers.... i am perfectly aware of the definitions and the graphical nature of many one and onto. however this particular type is proving elusive to my intellect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the general idea:

Onto: The $2\sin(x)$ term does not really matter since it is bounded. The cubic polynomial $\to \pm \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

One-One: The derivative is $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 6x + 12 - 2\cos(x) = 3(x + 1)^2 + 9 - 2\cos(x)$. Since $\cos(x) \leq 1$, what can you conclude about the derivative?

Comment: obviously it is greater than 0. hence the function is increasing and hence one one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $f'(x)=3x^2+6x+12-2\cos x$.

Now $3x^2+6x+12=3((x+1)^2)+9\ge 9$. Thus $f'(x)\ge 7$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The derivative can be written as

$$f'(x) = 3(x + 1)^2 + 9 - 2 \cos x$$

Now $|\cos x| \le 1$ for all $x$, so the derivative has some nice properties....